# Javascript SQL request Bad Field Error in where clause

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

the Code is supposed to update the score only if there is no score with the same email greater than the current score, instead it displays the error:

```
Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'li' in 'where clause'
```

```
function postScores(useremail, username, scoreValue, leaderboardName) {
    if (leaderboardName === "GHOSTS" || leaderboardName === "PACMAN" || leaderboardName === "OVERALL") {
        connection.query('UPDATE SCORES_' + leaderboardName + ' SET SCORES=' + scoreValue + ' WHERE SCORES < ' + scoreValue + ' AND USER_EMAIL=' + useremail,
            function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Failed to Update. Attempting to Insert.");
                    console.log("Error: " + err);
                    connection.query(
                        'INSERT INTO SCORES_' + leaderboardName + '(USER_EMAIL, USER_NAME, SCORES) VALUES (?,?,?)', [
                            useremail, username, scoreValue
                        ],
                        function(err, rows, fields) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Total Failure. Systems down");
                            } else {
                                console.log("Success. Inserted new Scores");
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    } else {
        // Reference to Non-Existent Leaderboard
        return console.log('Specified Leaderboard of the name ' + leaderboardName + ' does not Exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: Should USER_EMAIL have quotes around it (as you're inserting a string)?

Comment: Using place holders would be better that quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UPDATE query, don't concatenate raw data into the values, use placeholders and pass an array for the values, in the same way as your INSERT query.

An unquoted string value is likely causing the SQL syntax error. By using placeholders, you don't need to handle quotes in the values.

```
connection.query('UPDATE SCORES_' + leaderboardName + ' SET SCORES = ? WHERE SCORES < ? AND USER_EMAIL = ?',
    [scoreValue, scoreValue, useremail],
    function (err, rows, fields) {
```